# react-native-reanimated bottom list, item exiting

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I'd like to create an animation that draws a list of new messages at the bottom of the screen and then removes them after a certain time. How to fix the bottom list so that if I delete an item from the list, the animation does not jump?!

*My dependencies:*

- "react-native": "0.71.8",
- "react-native-reanimated": "^3.1.0",

*The following code section illustrates the problem:*

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import Animated, {BounceIn, BounceOut} from 'react-native-reanimated';

export default function App(): JSX.Element {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([
    'ipsum # 1',
    'ipsum # 2',
    'ipsum # 3',
    'ipsum # 4',
    'ipsum # 5',
  ]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.mesagesContainer}>
        {messages.map(message => (
          <Animated.View
            key={message}
            style={styles.mesageContainer}
            entering={BounceIn}
            exiting={BounceOut}>
            <Text>{message}</Text>
            <Pressable
              onPress={() =>
                setMessages(messages.filter(item => item !== message))
              }>
              <Text style={styles.messageText}>remove</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </Animated.View>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  mesagesContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 50,
    width: '70%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  mesageContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 4,
    borderRadius: 8,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginVertical: 2,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  messageText: {
    marginLeft: 3,
    color: 'red',
  },
});
```